# ZXing - Integrate to Android Application

Tags: android, zxing

I have imported ZXing as library to my project. I am not copying code, I am just importing the ZXing project into my application project, and added it as a library.

What i want to do is, when I click on a button, I want to start the CaptureActivity.java in the ZXing library, and what ZXing to handle the decode and show the result.

Here is what I did... on the button click..

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            i.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivity(i);
```

Added CaptureActivity.java in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Added permission for camera,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Right now, the CaptureActivity recognises the QRCode, displays Found URL, and just  closes the Preview Screen.. I want the application to display the result of the scan, which I think the original application does...

How do I get this functionality?

Comment: You should startActivityForResult() and handle it in onActivityResult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its a small change in the way, the intent is called...

I changed the intent to the following and the result is displayed...

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivity(i);
```

Result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at [ScanningViaIntent](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) in ZXing's Wiki